Discord.py ephemeral not working inside followup_message
I've encountered an issue where follow-up messages sent with ephemeral=True after deferring the initial response using interaction.defer() are not being sent as ephemeral in Discord.py. Is this a known limitation or or am I missing something ?
deferring the initial response using interaction.defer() are not being sent as ephemeral in Discord.py.

Please provide your code. Without it nobody is going to be able to help you

Using interaction.followup.send("Just an example message", ephemeral=True) will not work. Instead, you will have to set ephemeral=True inside of interaction.response.defer(). Check out the code snippet below
import discord

@bot.tree.command()
async def with_defer(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    # The message below will be hidden from other users.
    await interaction.followup.send("Hey! This is a ephemeral message!")

